# VS2010 Web Deploy only leave extra files with specific extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, webdeploy

I'm deploying my ASP.NET-MVC3 application to an IIS7 server.

Publishing to web works fine if I check "Leave extra files on destination (do not delete)".

If the checkbox is not checked, it usually fails with this error:

> Error 65  Web deployment task failed.((2013.07.10. 17:06:09) An error
>   occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)
>
> (2013.07.10. 17:06:09) An error occurred when the request was
>   processed on the remote computer.
>
> An error was encountered when processing operation 'Delete File' on
>   'App_tracelog.svclog'.
>
> The error code was 0x80070020.
>
> The process cannot access
>   'D:\WebSites\app\Admin\App_tracelog.svclog' because it is being
>   used by another process.      0   0   AdminApp

Clearly the tracelog cannot be deleted as it is currently written by the application.

I don't want to leave all files on the server on the deploy, so I first thought that switching my application off, deploy, and switching it on would be a good solution. It works, but I haven't been able to do it automatically (on pressing publish). (Is there a way?)

I later realized, that deleting the tracelog is bad practice. The log should be preserved, it is there so I can later access and read it.

I want to delete nearly everything from the folder I deploy to, except my logs, and some of my backed up files. Is there a way to to force the deploy to automatically clean that folder from files **except** a few (with the extension .tracelog, .bak, .log, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so in the following manner:

- create **YourWebProjectName.wpp.targets** file next to you the project file with the following content:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipXMLFiles">
    <SkipAction></SkipAction>
    <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
    <AbsolutePath>$(_DestinationContentPath)\\*.xml</AbsolutePath>
    <Apply>Destination</Apply>
    <XPath></XPath>
  </MsDeploySkipRules>
  </Project>
  ```

Change `YourWebProjectName` accordingly.

You can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18273301/1990682) for more details on how to to have a more grained control on which folders/files get deleted/synchronised.

NB: VisualStudio tends to cache wpp.targets files so if you use VS to esecute your publish, I suggest you to restart VS after you modify them.