# Excluding a folder from deployment and from additional file removal

Tags: iis, web-deployment, webdeploy

If a deployment has a folder full of user generated content, I exclude it from publishing in the `.pubxml` file with:

```
<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>somefoldername</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
```

If you use the **Remove additional files at destination** option for deploying, files in this folder are still removed from the live server.

```
<SkipExtraFilesOnServer>False</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
```

Is there any way to make the deployment process, including the clean-up of the live server, ignore a specified folder?

Comment: "Remove additional files at destination" seems to be doing what it is suppose to be doing? What do you get if that is unchecked?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I uncheck it then none of my deployment is 'cleaned up' by the file removal process. If I refactor some code or script names and deploy, both the old and new are left on the server. If I check the box, all of my user generated content gets cleared, even in excluded folders. It is the combination of the two options together that I am interested in achieving.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specifying folders not to sync in Web Deploy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245239/specifying-folders-not-to-sync-in-web-deploy)